# "error: duplicate case value" error when using goto in switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, label, goto, string-literals

I was trying to use the `goto` statement to travel between different `switch-cases`. I understand, it's not preferable to use `goto` as it would make the program tough to understand, but I really need it.

Here's the example version of my code:

```
switch(something){
    case "c1":
        //some code
        break;
    case "c2":
       //some code
       break;
    case "c3":
        if(condition1)
            goto case "c1";
        if(condition2)
            goto case "c2";
    default:
        break;
}
```

Now, when I run the code, I get the following error `error: duplicate case value` which applies to both `goto case "c1"` and `goto case "c2"`.

I'm not sure why the compiler is thinking the `goto` on a `switch-case` is redefining another `case` in the switch statement with the same condition and hence throwing that duplicate error. Any help and reasons for this error is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to compare a string, and then do a thing depending on the string, use something like a `std::map` where the key is the string, and the value is a function object that you can call and "do the thing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case the switch statement does not make a sense because you are using string literals as case labels.

```
switch(something){
    case "c1":
        //some code
        break;
    case "c2":
       //some code
       break;
    case "c3":
        if(condition1)
            goto case "c1";
        if(condition2)
            goto case "c2";
    default:
        break;
}
```

The expression in the switch statement is converted to an integral or enumeration type that can not be implicitly converted to pointers or string literals.

Maybe you need to use character literals as for example

```
case 'c1':
```

The second problem is you may not use case labels with goto statements. You may use with the goto statements only labels that are presented as identifiers. The syntax of the goto statement is

```
goto identifier ;
```

So the compiler thinks that the case labels used in goto statements redefine already introduced case labels.

Comment: I'm using string literals as a `case` because `something` is a character of a string that changes every time. I'm sure I say the use of `goto case "c1"` somewhere, anyhow, is there an alternative to this?

Comment: @PranavDesai As I wrote you may not do this.

Comment: I heavily assumed some concepts and hence the error reflecting in my code. Thanks for clarifying.